# Use same plan or pack together several insert statement and get a lot of single use plans?

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

What would be the best for SQL-Server 2012.

If we have a collection that needs to be inserted to the db.
One way is to execute each insert with a parameterized query like this (pseudo)

```
foreach(car in cars)
(
  sqlstring = "INSERT INTO car(name, type) VALUES(@name, @type)
  execute
)
```

Another approach is to each the insert statements together and only execute ones.

```
foreach(car in cars)
(
      sqlstring += "INSERT INTO car(name, type) VALUES(@name+index, @type+index)
)
execute
```

The second approach will get a lot of cached plans that will probably only be used once.
The first approach I think is faster.

There is a third option I know of to use TableValued parameters but let's skip this for this discussion.

What would be the best approach regarding performance?

Comment: You need to parameterize your queries. I know this is pseudocode but it is also wide open to sql injection the way you put this together. You would probably be a lot happier in the long run if you split your application into multiple layers and get the data out of the front end.

Comment: How many `cars` are we talking about? 10? 100? 1000? 1.000.000?

Comment: it could be up to a couple of thousands

Comment: also this is a Query that will run as often as a couple of hundred times a day each time with different Count in the collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a couple of thousand rows, creating an enormous statement to hold everything isn't practical -- parsing the statement and generating a plan will become a noticeable overhead, especially if the query size itself becomes variable. Use single `INSERT` statements instead, but wrap them in a transaction to minimize the overhead of logging.

Although you've discarded table-valued parameters, those would also be a viable solution (certainly almost always preferable to huge parameter lists, though there are specialized cases where those work better).

Answer (score 0):

There's another option that would arguably work better given that you're working with SQL Server 2012: just do them as one insert:

```
sqlstring = "INSERT INTO car(name, type) VALUES "

foreach(car in cars)
(
      sqlstring += "(@name+index, @type+index),"
)
//Remove last comma
execute
```

It will treat the insert as a single batch, which should generally be better than a lot of single inserts (of course, as always, it's best to test this to be sure).

Comment: This should be parameterized or it is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: This method is not very practical for large amounts of data -- the bottleneck will become parsing the statement.

Comment: Yes but this will also produce a lot of single use plans. The question is if that is a bad idea?

Comment: @Addeladde My experience on this is that you would want to be sure that the "optimize for ad hoc workloads" server setting was on using this method. It's not necessarily a bad idea, and doing it as a single insert would be better than a multitude of inserts. My personal preference would be to use TVPs or XML into a stored proc, or using bcp/bulk insert if there was a large amount of data.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I agree. I was trying to answer in a way that used the same style as the original example. For a large volume of data, there are a lot of better options.

Comment: In most cases there are only a couple of rows but on some occasions there can be upp to maybe 2000 rows. We have about 400 single use plans and about 1500 multi use plans so I really dont want to switch on optimize for adhoc querys.

Comment: @Addeladde For what it's worth, the optimize setting is usually pretty safe, but I can appreciate your concern about it. Some information here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35500/why-would-i-not-use-the-sql-server-option-optimize-for-ad-hoc-workloads

Comment: @JasonWhitish Thanks I will try to turning that option on.
I thought that if Single Use plans where more used than multi use plans then it should be turned on.